# How to count instances in table in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to produce a table which has the counts of each instance a variable appears in a dataframe grouped by variables in one column

My table looks like this:

```
Infected  Education age    sex    race     Score
       0      missing   35   Female   missing   1371.07
       1      Higher    39   Female   Black     1466.49
       0      Higher    27   Female   Asian     8020.09
       1      A-level   36   Female   Black     398.67
       1      GCSE      32   Male     Other     1312.80
```

This is the code used to produce it:

```
 df<-  structure(list(Infected = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), Education = structure(c(1L, 4L, 4L, 
    2L, 3L), .Label = c("missing", "A-level", "GCSE", "Higher"), class = "factor"), 
        age = c(35L, 39L, 27L, 36L, 32L), sex = structure(c(3L, 3L, 
        3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Missing_Other", "Male", "Female"
        ), class = "factor"), race = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
        4L), .Label = c("missing", "Asian", "Black", "Other", "White"
        ), class = "factor"), Score = c(1371.06994628906, 1466.48999023438, 
        8020.08984375, 398.670013427734, 1312.80004882812)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(221L, 
    261L, 444L, 561L, 702L))
```

I have already attempted using the dplyr package to count and group instances but I'm new to R so I'm afraid my code isnt giving my desired result.

This is the code i've already tried but im not sure how i can alter this to produce my desired outcome:

```
table <-df %>% group_by(Infection) %>% count(sex,Education,age,race,Score)
```

My desired output would look like this:

```
                 Infection_1     Infection_0    Infection_All
**ALLSex**                 
Male                 1(0%)         0(0%)            1(20%)
Female               2(40%)         2(40%)           4(80%
**Education**
Missing              0(0%)          1(20%)           1(20%)
Higher               1(20%)         1(20%)           2(40%)
Alevel               1(20%)         0(0%)            2(20%)
GCSE                 1(20%)         0(0%)            1(20%)
**Race**
Black                2(40%)         0(0%)            2(40%)
Asian                1(20%)         0(0%)            1(20%)
Other                0(0%)          1(20%)           1(20%)
White                0(0%)          0(0%)            0(0%)
Other                1(20%)         0(0%)            1(20%)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reproducible example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some `dplyr` steps to achieve the desired table. Here is how you can get the counts in a `tibble`.

```
df %>% 
  select(-Score, -age) %>%
  gather(key="Category", value="Level", -Infected) %>%
  mutate(Infected = paste("Infected", Infected, sep="_")) %>%
  group_by(Category, Level, Infected) %>%
  count() %>%
  spread(Infected, n, fill = 0) %>%
  mutate(Infected_all = Infected_0 + Infected_1)
```

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   Category, Level [10]
   Category  Level   Infected_0 Infected_1 Infected_all
   <chr>     <chr>        <dbl>      <dbl>        <dbl>
 1 Education A-level          0          1            1
 2 Education GCSE             0          1            1
 3 Education Higher           1          1            2
 4 Education missing          1          0            1
 5 race      Asian            1          0            1
 6 race      Black            0          2            2
 7 race      missing          1          0            1
 8 race      Other            0          1            1
 9 sex       Female           2          2            4
10 sex       Male             0          1            1
Warning message:
attributes are not identical across measure variables;
they will be dropped
```

Here are the steps described.

Discard unnecessary columns with `select` then pivot the columns using `gather` and set the names of the resulting columns.

```
> df %>% 
+   select(-Score, -age) %>%
+   gather(key="Category", value="Level", -Infected)
   Infected  Category   Level
1         0 Education missing
2         1 Education  Higher
3         0 Education  Higher
4         1 Education A-level
5         1 Education    GCSE
6         0       sex  Female
7         1       sex  Female
8         0       sex  Female
9         1       sex  Female
10        1       sex    Male
11        0      race missing
12        1      race   Black
13        0      race   Asian
14        1      race   Black
15        1      race   Other
```

Replace the value of Infected column with its name and value using `mutate`. These will be used as column names later on. Perform the counting as you already know.

```
> df %>% 
+   select(-Score, -age) %>%
+   gather(key="Category", value="Level", -Infected) %>%
+   mutate(Infected = paste("Infected", Infected, sep="_")) %>%
+   group_by(Category, Level, Infected) %>%
+   count()
# A tibble: 12 x 4
# Groups:   Category, Level, Infected [12]
   Category  Level   Infected       n
   <chr>     <chr>   <chr>      <int>
 1 Education A-level Infected_1     1
 2 Education GCSE    Infected_1     1
 3 Education Higher  Infected_0     1
 4 Education Higher  Infected_1     1
 5 Education missing Infected_0     1
 6 race      Asian   Infected_0     1
 7 race      Black   Infected_1     2
 8 race      missing Infected_0     1
 9 race      Other   Infected_1     1
10 sex       Female  Infected_0     2
11 sex       Female  Infected_1     2
12 sex       Male    Infected_1     1
```

Pivot the rows back to columns using `spread` function. Add the Infected all column using `mutate`.

Then you can use other packages like `xtable` to format the output.

Comment: Nice answer! Just for info though: `gather` and `spread` are on their way out and will be replaced by `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` at some point in the future.

Comment: @Emer Thank you very much for your brilliant and detailed answer. Could i use dplyr if I was to add percentages into each cell? I have attempted to add  %>% 
  summarise(paste0((n/nrow(df))*100, '%')) to the end of the column which returns an error

Comment: @H.B for the percentage add ```%>% mutate(Infected_all_pct = paste0(Infected_all / nrow(df) * 100, '%'))```